# Removing the name of mulilevel index

Tags: python, pandas

I created the mulitlevel DataFrame:

```
         Price
Country England Germany      US
sys dis
23  0.8   300.0   300.0   800.0
24  0.8  1600.0   600.0   600.0
27  1.0  4000.0  4000.0  5500.0
30  1.0  1000.0  3000.0  1000.0
```

Right now I want to remove the name: Country, and add the index from 0 to..

```
               Price 
     sys dis  England Germany   US 
  0  23  0.8   300.0   300.0   800.0
  1  24  0.8  1600.0   600.0   600.0
  2  27  1.0  4000.0  4000.0  5500.0
  3  30  1.0  1000.0  3000.0  1000.0
```

This is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sys':[23,24,27,30],'dis': [0.8, 0.8, 1.0,1.0], 'Country':['US', 'England', 'US', 'Germany'], 'Price':[500, 1000, 1500, 2000]})


df = df.set_index(['sys','dis', 'Country']).unstack().fillna(0)
```

Can I have some hints how to solve it? I don't have too much experience with multilevel DataFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.reset_index()
df.columns.names =[None, None]


df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Price'], [u'England', u'Germany', u'US']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2]],
       names=[None, u'Country'])
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand df.columns.names =[None, None] correctly. It is used for a multilevel Dataframe. Do we have to use twice None, because there is two level Dataframe? What about If I want to drop Price header too?

Comment: I understood it! Thank you so much for helping me out! :)

Answer (score 2):

Best I've got for now:

```
df.rename_axis([None, None], 1).reset_index()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

for the index

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

For the columns

```
 df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)
```

Comment: when I use df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1), the headers are replaced by Price, Price, Price. I can use rename function, but maybe there is smarter way o do it.

Comment: good luck. sometimes you have to write some additional lines to get exacly what u need